# how to make check/uncheck randomly in cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to make random check/uncheck(miss) checkboxes

```
cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check()/uncheck()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()` to generate a number and based on the number, you can check uncheck on the checkbox.

```js
//Generate Random numbers between 1 and 100
cy.wrap(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)).then((num) => {
  if(num <=50){
    cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').check()
  }
  else {
    cy.get('[type="checkbox"]').uncheck()
  }
})
```

Comment: I want to use assertion for this checkbox. It depends on duration. If it's checked duration = forever, if not = a month.    `cy.wrap(cy.get('span.ant-checkbox').should('have.class','ant-checkbox-checked')).then((a) => {
      if a == true {
        cy.log('Forever')
      }
    })`

Comment: Please open a new question for this as it goes beyond the scope of the current one.

Comment: Generating 0 or 1 should be enough instead of between 1 and 100.